# How to trace USB traffic in peripheral or OTG mode?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, usb

I've set up a Raspbian Jessie on a Raspberry Pi Zero to use USB OTG with the `dwc2` module.
What I'd like to do now is **sniff incoming USB traffic on the peripheral  side**. I found and tested the `usbmon` kernel module, but it (apparently, to the extent of my limited knowledge) doesn't seem to work: nothing is recorded.

For testing purposes, I tried the exact same thing on the host side (another computer on Linux) and I can successfully trace USB data with `usbmon`. Unfortunately, this is not what I need.

In conclusion: is it possible ? And if yes, how? Can I use `usbmon` or do I have do to something else (e.g. recompile kernel with specific options)?

Answer (score 1):

the tool `USBMon` is unfinished

there is a kernel module with the same name which is up to date

make sure that the kernel module `usbmon` is available load it (`modprobe usbmon`) and the you can sniff USB traffic using

- `usbdump` (as a frontend to the `usbmon` kernel module)
- following the instructions on https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/usbmon.txt
- wireshark https://www.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB

see also http://discussions.flightaware.com/ads-b-flight-tracking-f21/monitoring-usb-utilization-on-raspberry-pi-t20691.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To clarify, I'm using the ubmon kernel module, not the tool. I did follow the instructions from kernel.org (maybe I should've mentionned it. My problem is that I can't use Wireshark or any similar tool because usbmon is not sniffing anything, apparently because the USB port is in device mode (and not host mode).
Also, your last link seems interesting, but it seems broken?

Comment: yes link was broken, sorry. did you load the usbmon module with `modprobe` ? if yes install and run `dumpcap -D` **as root** to see the interfaces you can capture on. dumpcap is in the *tshark* package. in general until you know where the error is run everything as root...

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have a RPi at hand, I cannot say for sure it this will work for you or not, but I've successfully managed monitoring USB traffic on a remote machine using the `tcpdump` and `wireshark`, with the following command:

`$ ssh user@remotehost 'tcpdump -U -i usbmon2 -w -' | wireshark -k -i -`

Here, `usbmon2` the `2` is for the Bus ID where your USB device is connected on. You can get this with `lsusb`.

Comment: This is very interesting, but unfortunately not what I'm looking for at the moment... 
I need to sniff USB traffic on the device side (the Rpi), before any network connection is made, mainly because the Rpi is later configured to be an Ethernet gadget, and without having any specific knowledge of the host I connect the Rpi to.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging around, it doesn't seem possible (or if it is, I just can't find any information anywhere) to trace USB traffic when the controller is in **device** (or peripheral) mode. It's only possible when the controller is configured as a **host**.

As no trace is generated by `usbmon`, I unfortunately can't use any tools (Wireshark, dumpcap...) because they need that trace in the first place.

So what I'll be trying to do now is to either modify the `libcomposite` kernel module to add debugging information or even write a specific module designed for sniffing (but this is way above my current knowledge in the matter at the moment).

Comment: Did you have any progress with that since you asked the question?